# How to add an icon to the IntelliJ status bar

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I am writing an IntelliJ plugin and I want to add an icon to the status bar showing that the plugin is running (branding reasons).

From what I figured out, I need to create an action in plugin.xml and specify that it should be in the status bar group:

```
<action id="MyAction" class="ActionClass" icon="icons/icon.png">
<add-to-group group-id="???" />
</action>
```

The only problem is that I cannot find the group-id string for the status bar.

Is this the right way to add an icon there? If yes, where can I find the group-id string for the status bar?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right way is to implement StatusBarWidget and register it (StatusBar.addWidget). You may look at IntelliJ CE sources for this API usage examples.

Comment: Yup, it's something like

    statusBar.addWidget(aStatus);